# Spring getBeanNamesForType is not working well

Tags: java, spring

I have simple context configuration

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.ResolvableType;

import java.util.Arrays;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        String[] namesForType = ctx.getBeanNamesForType(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(Transformer.class, Integer.class, String.class));

        System.out.println("namesForType = " + Arrays.toString(namesForType));
    }

    @Bean
    public Transformer<Integer, String> stringTransformer() {
        return new Transformer<Integer, String>();
    }
}
```

and simple class

```
package com.example;

public class Transformer<F, T> {

    T transform(F from) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I start the application, output is **namesForType = []**

In case when creation of bean is changed into separated class like

```
    @Bean
    public Transformer<Integer, String> stringTransformer() {
        return new Transformer<Integer, String>(){};
    }
```

The output is **namesForType = [stringTransformer]**

Comment: What do you mean by separate class? I don't see a separate class in your code.

Comment: Sorry this is anonymous class `new Transformer<Integer, String>(){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is already reported in Spring JIRA. Please vote for this issue.
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14118

Answer (score 0):

That is correct behaviour. Before the @Bean annotation is used it will not be picked up in the spring context.

Comment: This is not true. Bean named "stringTransformer" is in context, but spring cannot get it using resolvable type. Try this code before context close: `ctx.getBean("stringTransformer");`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in `org.springframework.core.ResolvableType#isInstance` in `obj.getClass()`

```
public boolean isInstance(Object obj) {
    return (obj != null && isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()));
}
```

and

```
public boolean isAssignableFrom(Class<?> other) {
    return isAssignableFrom(forClass(other), null);
}
```

because `forClass(...)` create resolvable type `Transformer<?, ?>`

But i can't understand how

```
@Autowire
private Transformer<String, Integer> transformer;
```

can inject the correct bean.